# Angular + Webpack: long browser refresh period on development

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, asp.net-core, uglifyjs

I'm using Angular 4 template +Asp Core + webpack in VS 2017

I want to uglify and minify Angular code so I've call UglifyJsPlugin in webpack.config.js:

```
    const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const merge = require('webpack-merge');
    const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
    const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

    module.exports = (env) => {
        // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
        const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
        const sharedConfig = {
            stats: { modules: false },
            context: __dirname,
            resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
            output: {
                filename: '[name].js',
                publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
            },
            module: {
                rules: [
                    { test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                    { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                    { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                    { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
                ]
            },
            plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()
                     ,new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(     //HERE
            {sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true,
             compressor: {warnings: false,},
            }),  


            ]  
        };
......
```

After that browser refresh period in development mode increases from 6 seconds to 22 seconds,I only added this call:

> ,new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true,minimize:
>   true,compressor: {warnings: false,},}),

It is possible to run it only on deploy/publish the app,not in dev mode, maybe to use `const isDevBuild` to conditionally call the plugin?
Are my call UglifyJsPlugin options good for production?
thanks

Comment: Normally you have a base webpack config file with the common things and two different files that extend this, one for development and one for production. There are a lot more/different things you want to do in your production build. Strongly suggest you have a look at [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io) since it abstracts a lot of these things.

Comment: Hi.I'm not using Angular CLI,it is possible to use const isDevBuild to conditionally call the plugin?thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to with isDebBuild. Normally one would have two (or more) config files for webpack and different scripts in package.json for build, dev, etc. You can have a look [here for examples](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter)

Comment: Hi.I'm not so experienced to modify the project for add a new file for dev/build...About that const in webpack.config.js I see some code like this:  , use: isDevBuild ? ... and on top it is defined    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);   thaks.

Comment: Assuming 'prod' is set as env variable when you run the production build then yes, it will work.

Comment: but how to call the plugin conditionally with that const?

Comment: The plugins array in the config is an array, if you want to use a plugin for dev and a different one for prod you can do it inline with the ternary operator: isDevBuild ? new PluginA() : new PluginB(). Otherwise just declare the array somewhere above and conditionally add the plugin to it.

Comment: Indeed there are sections only for productions where I can add this  plugins: [].concat(isDevBuild ? [ new ..... thanks